# HTML closing tag with same align as open tag in Intellij

Tags: html, intellij-idea

It try to configure the code style of html in IntelliJ.
Is it possible to configure it, that the closing tag has the same "alignment" as the open tag?

Here is my example Code:

```
<div>
    <p>Test</p></div>
```

If i auto format the code (ctr+alt+L) the code should be format like this:

```
<div>
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Edit: The answer from lena is correct it works for the p tag, but i also have a problem with the p-button from primeNG.

```
<p-button [label]="myLabel"
      (onClick)="clickMethod"
      [disabled]="this.shouldDisabled"></p-button>
```

should format like this:

```
<p-button [label]="myLabel"
      (onClick)="clickMethod"
      [disabled]="this.shouldDisabled">
</p-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML**, **Other**, try removing `p` from **Don't break if inline content** list, then re-format the code with `Ctr+Alt+L`

Comment: thank you, it works. But i have also another problem, i've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

add prettier extension
this is the link https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10456-prettier